# Ember Data breaks when fetching JSON from Node + Express REST server

Tags: node.js, rest, ember.js, express, ember-data

I am trying to fetch JSON data from REST server built with Node.js and Express and then use it as a model in my Ember#Route.

The data I am trying to fetch:

```
var books = [
    { id: 98, author: 'Stanisław Lem', title: 'Solaris' },
    { id: 99, author: 'Andrzej Sapkowski', title: 'Wiedźmin' }
];
```

The model I use:

```
App.Book = DS.Model.extend({
    id: DS.attr('number'),
    author: DS.attr('string'),
    title: DS.attr('string')
});
```

I set up the RESTAdapter this way:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://localhost:8080' 
});
```

Mapping:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource("books");
});
```

My Route looks like this:

```
App.BooksRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return this.store.find('book');
    }
});
```

I am aware that ember-data follows certain convention when it comes to JSON files.
My server provides JSONs this way:

```
app.get('/books', function (request, response) {
    console.log('In GET function ');
    response.json({'books': books})
});
```

Then, after entering

```
http://localhost:8080/books
```

I get

```
{"books":[{"id":98,"author":"Stanisław Lem","title":"Solaris"},{"id":99,"author":"Andrzej Sapkowski","title":"Wiedźmin"}]}
```

but when I enter

```
http://localhost:8080/#/books
```

ember-data throws long error list that begins with:

```
"Error while processing route: books" "invalid 'in' operand record._attributes"    
"ember$data$lib$system$model$attributes$$getValue@http://localhost:8080/static/ember-data.js:8176:1
ember$data$lib$system$model$attributes$$attr/<@http://localhost:8080/static/ember-data.js:8202:26
computedPropertySet@http://localhost:8080/static/ember.prod.js:11882:15
computedPropertySetWithSuspend@http://localhost:8080/static/ember.prod.js:11842:9
makeCtor/Class@http://localhost:8080/static/ember.prod.js:33887:17
...
```

and now I don't know what is wrong and how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the mistake I made was in declaring model. ID attribute shouldn't be declared here, correct model looks like this:

```
App.Book = DS.Model.extend({
    author: DS.attr('string'),
    title: DS.attr('string')
});
```